# The action 'google' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, openid

I am trying to integrate OpenID login with Google to my Rails website. I am following the [Devise & Omniauth](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) overview. For some reason, I am getting the error,

```
Unknown action

The action 'google' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

My `routes.rb` has,

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

`users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` has,

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:google]

  def google
     .....
  end       
end
```

My user.rb has got,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :omniauthable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
  :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def self.find_for_open_id(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
     ....
  end
end
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
```

This is all done as per the wiki page. When I click the URL, it takes me to google and after entering credentials, I am redirected back. This is where the failure happening.

I am not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you added something like `config.omniauth :google` to devise.rb initializer?

Comment: @nash - yes. I forgot to mention that. I have edited the post. Please take a look.

Comment: @Appu Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I use Omniauth (without Devise) and the correct action for Google is `:google_oauth2`.